# What is the shorcut in visual studio to switch from code behind to Xaml Code?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm used to press shift+F7 to switch between my code behind and the designer (which takes between 1 and 5 seconds to load) then I always have to click on View Xaml to modify my XAML code.

I don't find any shortcut in Tools/Options/Keyboard to go directly (from code behind to XAML code). How can I do that ?

Comment: I don't have the answer and I will be watching your question.  However,  Shift+F7 doesn't work for me.  
I usually press F7 to go from XAML to code behind.  Then I just right click and select View Designer and select XAML.  Hope someone has better solution.

Comment: Shift+F7 is mapped to View.ViewDesigner in my visual studio

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In VS2008, while in code-behind of your XAML page (.xaml.cs), pressing SHIFT-F7 will take you to the XAML Designer or the XAML code page, depending on which one had the latest focus. Pressing SHIFT-F7 again will take you from the XAML code page to the designer and vice versa.

While in the XAML designer or XAML code page, pressing F7 takes you to the related code behind page.

UPDATE.
Applicable for later versions (e.g. MS VS 2015 too).

Comment: SHIFT-F7 always take me to the XAML Designer :(

Comment: I find it will go to the Designer if that's what you last had open and the XAML markup if that's what you had open.

Comment: Can confirm `Shift-F7` works in VS 2019. Also brendan's comment that if the Designer was last open that is displayed, and if the markup was last open, then this is displayed. This corresponds to the command `View.ViewDesigner` in `Options > Environment > Keyboard`. Alternatively `View > Designer` from the main display.

Answer (score 8):

I've finally found the solution for VS 2010:

F7: switch between Code Behind and XAML (Design or Markup depending on last used)
Shift+F7: switch between XAML (Design) and XAML (Markup).

F7 shortcut mapping should look like "View.ToggleDesigner (F7 (Global))"
Shift+F7 shortcut mapping should look like "View.ViewDesigner (Shift+F7 (Global))" and "View.ViewMarkup (Shift+F7 (HTML Source Editor View))" (two mappings for one shortcut).

Answer (score 4):

When I first installed VS2010, my keyboard mappings were set to (Default).  The default setting had View.ViewDesigner mapped to "Shift-F7 (HTML Editor Source View)".  To get the shortcut to work in all views, I had to change the mapping to "Shift-F7 (Global)".  Changing the keyboard mappings to "Visual C# 2005" worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2008:

F7 goes from XAML to Code Behind,
Shift-F7 goes from Code Behind to XAML

Comment: SHIFT-F7 goes to the XAML design, not in the XAML code page, that's my problem

Comment: Hmm, goes to the code page for me. But then I have the designer turned off.

Comment: how did you do to turn of the designer ?

Comment: Tools->Options->Text Editor->XAML->Miscellaneous, check "Always open documents in full XAML view".

Comment: It's already check, Shift+F7 in a UserControl will bring me to the XAML view but on a Window it brings me always to the Designer View :(

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2012, F7 builds the solution.

- Shift-F7: goes from code-behind to XAML Ctrl
- Ctrl-Alt-0: goes from XAML to code-behind

It's in the View menu, but not an obvious keystroke.  Tools-Customize...Keyboard... to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Download dpack for visual studio (free) - then F7 will always switch to the "other" view.  Plenty of other great features in there too.

Comment: I already have DPack, it's a great add-in, I Love the file and classes indexing, nice feature instead of using the Solution Explorer, but F7 always go from the designer or xaml code to the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

-->Tools --> Options --> Keyboard
Seek "view.view..

View.ViewCode [F7] (global) Assign

View.ViewDesigner [Shif+F7] (global) Assign