# Visual Studio shortcut key to WFC service code behind

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013

I am currently working in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 in a WebForms project. For every file the shortcut key `F7` will bring me to the files code behind.

However for a WFC service or .svc file that looks like:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XXX.Web.Svc.XXX" CodeBehind="XXX.svc.cs" %>
```

F7 does not appear to work. I have also test on a brand new project and it exhibits the same behavior.

I love my keyboard shortcuts, and I was wondering if anyone knew of one to for this, or how to set one?

I apologize in advance if this is not a question for StackOverflow, I did see other questions for Visual Studio shortcuts on here as well as a Visual Studio tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When right-clicking on the .svc file and selecting "View Markup", this will bring you to the actual .svc file instead of the .svc.cs. Knowing this, you can go into  Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, then search for "View.ViewMarkup" and assign a shortcut there.

More information can be found in a previous Stack Overflow question:

[What is the shorcut in visual studio to switch from code behind to Xaml Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852389/what-is-the-shorcut-in-visual-studio-to-switch-from-code-behind-to-xaml-code)

Comment: I was actually looking for View.ViewCode, but your answer got me there. Thanks for the tip.